# Не подключается к БД, как правильно настроить web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Когда подключаюсь к БД, которая находится на удаленном сервере, приложение запускается как положено.

Как только пытаюсь подключиться к этой же БД, которая расположена на моем локальном sql сервере, сайт грузится и дальше никакого результата. Для локальной БД настроил следующую строку подключения и сам файл веб.конфиг:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ColorLongLifeDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ColorLongLife.mdf;Initial Catalog=ColorLongLife;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="SmtpServer" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpPort" value="587"/>
    <!-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
    <!-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
    <!-- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -->
    <add key="Email" value="mail@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="Password" value="9967689"/>

    <add key="SiteUrl" value="http://localhost:22493/"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/signin" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Черезsql manager sql studio захожу, без проблем подключаюсь к локальной БД. В чем ошибка в настройках подключения? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Строка подключение зависит от того какой SQL клиент вы используете, ниже вам дан пример подключения для SqlConnection, а ещё бывает OdbcConnection и OleDbConnection. Уточните какой клиент, и как вы делаете процедуру Connect.

Comment: Как звучит текст ошибки? Не видит сервер или не проходит авторизация?

Answer (score 1):

В секцию configuration вставить

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionName" connectionString="Server=<SQL_SERVER_ADDRESS>;Database=<DBNAME>;User Id=<USER>;Password=<PASSWORD>;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

В качестве SQL_SERVER_ADDRESS используйте имя машины и имя инстанса SQL Server, например Home-PC\SQLEXPRESS, где Home-PC имя вашей машины, а SQLEXPRESS - инстан

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте настройки пула IIS. LocalDb использует профиль пользователя - а потому важно, чтобы этот профиль был загружен.

Да и вообще LocalDb не рекомендуется использовать в веб-проектах. Попробуйте поставить себе нормальный SQL Server Express.

Integrated Security может плохо работать с имперсонацией, которую делает ASP.NET. Можете попробовать дать права на доступ к БД пользователю `IIUSR` - но лучше бы перейти на SQL авторизацию.

Comment: у меня стоит sql express. Как правильно указать в строке подключения?

Comment: Stefan Hansch, строка подключения не зависит от sql express. Строка подключения зависит от выбраного вами клиента и метода подключения этим клиентом к СУБД. В c# к СУБД можно подключится 10-ю способами - покажите какой способ выбрали вы. И ещё, вы должны сделать conn.Connect() - оно либо соиденит с базой, либо напишет ошибку. Какую всётаки ошибку оно пишет?

Comment: @nick_n_a глупость вы какую-то написали. Строка подключения именно что зависит от сервера - и она разная для Express и LocalDb. Очень разная.

Comment: @StefanHansch ну и вас же с удаленной базой работало - напишите так же, только указав свой сервер.